# Using QuerydslBinderCustomizer, how do I specify containsIgnoreCase for all String multi-valued query parameters?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

For my string query parameters, I can easily perform a case insensitive & contains search using `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`:

```
public interface CarRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<Car, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Car>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QCar> {
    
    @Override
    default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QCar car) {

        bindings.bind(String.class).first(
                (StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
```

So, for my url:

```
http://my-service/cars?make=toy&model=cam
```

I would get a car with make: Toyota and model: Camry

But if I want to search using a multi-valued query parameter:

```
http://my-service/cars?make=toy&make=hond
```

Only the first query parameter uses a case-insensitive and contains search. So, I get Toyota but I will not get Honda. That's expected though because the API specifies `first`.

I found `all` but how do I use it to ignore case and use contains? Here's what I want to do but this doesn't work as path is not a `StringPath`:

```
        bindings.bind(String.class).all(
                (path, value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
```

Comment: Any luck? I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: @JoshC. - Yes, I figured it out and will post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows:

```
public interface CarRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<Car, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Car>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QCar> {
    
    @Override
    default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QCar car) {

        bindings.bind(String.class).all(
                (StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> all) -> {
        
                BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
                all.forEach(value -> 
                     predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value)));
                return Optional.of(predicate);          
       });
```